# Selenium - Mobile Emulation works locally, but NOT works ONLY on CI/CD tool machines

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm working in a test automation using Selenium and Java, and I use bamboo as the CI/CD tool, which I use to run my Selenium tests.

And I automate tests to an application which works for some devices, in my case I choose to use iPhone X... If the application is accessed from any other device it will not work.

I have my test suite where I need to emulate a iPhone in the webbrowser, and so I did... and I have my test suite developed properly and working properly on any local machine that I try to run (windows or linux), and the mobile emulation works everything fine without problems...

But anytime when I try to run from the CI/CD tool, the application seems to be not identified as a supported device and the **test automation not works on CI/CD ONLY**, even though the log on the CI/CD tool shows to me that the capabilities are set correctly on chrome, and the resolution screen is also changed as I set I keep getting an screen from my app as if it was an unsupported device, but on the log of the CI/CD tool, the capabilities seems to be set correctly (including the userAgent)...

I have no idea why it just no works on the CI/CD tool, in ANY other machine that I try to run, it works properly...

It is not a version issue, because in local machine I have tested in Google Chrome versions: 91, 93, 94 and it works
But in the CI/CD tool, I have tested in Chrome versions: 90, 91, 93 and none of them has worked

This is the config that is set in my test code:

```
        Map<String, Object> deviceMetrics = new HashMap<>();
        deviceMetrics.put("width", 375);
        deviceMetrics.put("height", 812);
        deviceMetrics.put("pixelRatio", 3.0);

        Map<String, Object> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<>();
        mobileEmulation.put("deviceMetrics", deviceMetrics);
        String iphoneXUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU iPhone OS 15_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.0 Mobile/15A5341f Safari/604.1";
        mobileEmulation.put("userAgent", iphoneXUserAgent);
//      mobileEmulation.put("deviceName", "iPhone X");

        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.setCapability("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);
        chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);
        chromeOptions.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
```

And this is the list of all other capabilities that I have tried to use to see if it fixes my issue (and none of them has fixed my issue)

```
//      args.add("test-type");
        args.add("test-type=browser");
//      args.add("--user-agent=" + iphoneXUserAgent + "");
//      args.add("user-agent=" + iphoneXUserAgent + "");
        args.add("--allow-running-insecure-content");
        args.add("--disable-web-security");
        args.add("--ignore-ssl-errors=yes");
        args.add("incognito");
//      args.add("start-maximized");
        args.add("disable-infobars");
        args.add("--disable-default-apps");
//      args.add("--start-maximized");
        args.add("--ignore-certificate-errors");
        args.add("--disable-popup-blocking");
        args.add("--incognito");
        args.add("--touch-events=enabled");
//      args.add("--headless");
//      args.add("--profile-directory=Default");
//      args.add("--use-mobile-user-agent");
        args.add("--no-first-run");
//      args.add("--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required");
//      args.add("--disable-gesture-requirement-for-presentation");
        //      args.add("--allow-file-access-from-files");
        args.add("--window-size=375,812");
        args.add("--no-default-browser-check");
        args.add("--enable-automation");
        args.add("--disable-extensions");
        args.add("no-sandbox");
        args.add("--block-new-web-contents");
//      args.add("--diagnostics");
        args.add("--disable-blink-features");
        opts.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, opts);
//      opts.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
        opts.addArguments(args);
```

I have no idea anymore what can be causing this issue, why it just **not works ONLY on the CI/CD tool**

Do you guys have any idea about what I can do more to see if I can fix this issue?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please describe symptoms of your 'not works'. If you get any exception, update your question with stacktrace.

Comment: Hi @pburgr that's exactly the problem... there is no log different in the CI from the local machine... as I said on the issue, my application works only on some specific devices and that's why I set iPhone X on my automation, and when I run my test automation locally it works, but when I run on CI the application is recognized as an unsupported device by the application.